# Arccot becomes negative on taking reciprocal of argument

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Apparently the following relation holds;  $$\cot^{-1}\frac{1}{x}=-\cot^{-1}x$$

Is there a proof for this? I haven't seen this anywhere else.

I generalized this from $$-\cot^{-1}\frac{1}{\cot^2x}=\cot^{-1}\cot^2x$$
which I saw in the answer to a problem I was doing. Does it work only for these values or is it general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation is incorrect. It should be $\text{arccot } 1/x = -\text{arccot } x + \frac{\pi}{2}$, which follows from the identity $\text{arccot } x + \arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

If $y = \text{arccot } x, x = \cot y$, and if $y = \arctan x, x = \tan y$. Thus $\arctan 1/x = \text{arccot } x$ for $x \in \mathbb R^+$, and hence the corrected identity holds only in this domain, because of the ranges of $\cot y, \tan y$.

Comment: I get this answer, thanks. The expression in the question is the result of indefinite integration; so there's a constant added to $cot^{-1}\frac{1}{\cot^2x}$ after it. Is the answer I saw to the question still correct? As in, does $cot^{-1}\frac{1}{\cot^2x}$ simplify to $\cot^{-1}\cot^2x$alongwith some constant, making the answer still correct?

Comment: No, they are not the same, even after a phase shift. You can check this by graphing both functions on Desmos or GeoGebra.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot^{-1}x+\cot^{-1}\dfrac1x=\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}x+\dfrac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\dfrac1x$$

Now $\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}\dfrac1x=\tan^{-1}\dfrac{x+\dfrac1x}{1-x\cdot\dfrac1x}=\begin{cases}\dfrac\pi2 &\mbox{if } x>0\\
-\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } x<0\end{cases} $